# Adding and deleting data objects to an ObjectArray using a referenceArray

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I wrote a function to which I pass an array consisting of data objects "currentDataObjectArray". In addition, I pass an updated object array template to the function that tells which objects should be in the first array after the update "newDataElements".

All objects have an ID.
Therefore, I carry out a comparison of which objects have been added in "newDataElements" in order to then load the associated data into "currentDataObjectArray".
and which ones are deprecated and should be removed from currentDataObjectArray.

In many cases this works as it should, but sometimes the program gets stuck here and I don't recognize the weak point in the code.

```
//Improved code, thanks to Barmar 


async function UpdateDataObjectArray(currentDataObjectArray, newDataElements){

   const newIds = newDataElements.map(el => el.id);
   const currentIds = currentDataObjectArray.map(el => el.id);
    
   const newDataObjects = newIds.filter(x => !currentIds.includes(x));  //contains new ids
   const oldDataObjects = currentIds.filter(x => !newIds.includes(x));  //contains old ids
   const filtered = newDataElements.filter(el => newDataObjects.includes(el.id));
 
   //remove old dataObjects
   for(let i in oldDataObjects){            
      const idx = currentDataObjectArray.findIndex(el => el.id === oldDataObjects[i]); 
      currentDataObjectArray.splice(idx, 1);        
   }                
   
   //add new dataObjects
   if(newDataObjects.length > 0){
      let data = await LoadData(filtered);   
      currentDataObjectArray.push(...data);
      data = null;
   }
    
   return currentDataObjectArray; //updated
}
```

Here is the LoadData function:

```
async LoadData(newImages){

   const ids = newImages.map(el => el.id);
   const loader = new THREE.ImageBitmapLoader();   //from three.js library
                
   const sharedImageDatas = await Promise.all(
   ids.map(async (id) => {      
                            
      const url = app_constants.SECOND_IMAGE_LIBRARY + id;          
      let image = await loader.loadAsync(url);
                
      let canvas = new OffscreenCanvas(image.width, image.height); 
      let context = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
      context.drawImage( image, 0, 0 );
                
      let imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height);
                        
      const data = new Uint8Array(new SharedArrayBuffer(imageData.data.length));
      data.set(imageData.data, 0);
 
      image = canvas = context = imageData = null;
            
      return {id, data}; 
      })
   );   
        
   return sharedImageDatas;         
}
```

What worries me is that it works most of the time, but not always

Comment: There's no need for all those `if` statements that check the length of the array. If the array is empty, looping through it doesn't do anything.

Comment: I don't see how this could get stuck. That could only happen if you extend an array while you're looping over it, and you never modify the array you're looping over.

Comment: Learn to use `map`: `const newIds = newDataElements.map(el => el.id)`

Comment: You rarely need to use `apply()` in ES6, use `...`: currentDataObjectArray.push(...data)`

Comment: I use the code for two different data patterns. It always works for one. Then the error must lie in loading the second data pattern. I improved the code on your recommendation. You're right it's much more elegant

Comment: I have implemented your recommendations

Comment: Can you provide specific input data that's causing the problem?

Comment: I added my LoadData function. I have another similar function for fast-png, a png decoder. But it works perfectly.
With my second LoadData function (this one here) it also often works, but not always. That's what worries me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253079/discussion-between-spiri-and-barmar).

Comment: I still can't see anything that could cause the script to get stuck. There are no loops that could be infinite. Maybe the logic is not what you intend and you get unexpected results, but it shouldn't block.

Comment: Cause found, one of the image files was missing in the folder and that's why "let image = await loader.loadAsync(url);" was stuck

Comment: I was wondering about that, but I assumed it would get an error if it failed.

Comment: Maybe because i use the function in a worker. The only thing my app notices is that the worker is not returning anything and is therefore waiting the whole time for the data to be received. So there was never an error in the main thread.

Comment: I'm not experienced with web workers, so I'm not sure how to address that.